# How to Use hash table to solve questions?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

How to use hashtable to solve the given problem?
I was asked question like given a string of 0 and 1 like "001100" where 1 indicates system is updated and 0 indicate  unupdated  system. updated system(1) can update adjacent computer in one day. In one day only adjacent PC will be updated. So for above for day one string will become "011110" then day 2 it will be "111111" so total 2 days. How can i use hashtable for this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use a hash table to solve the problem? Do you have some idea that a hash table would be useful? Or do you just want to use a hash table for some reason?

Comment: I just want  a solution with lesser complexity. Person who interview me he said it is possible only through hash table

Comment: I don't see where a hash table would be especially relevant here unless you have a fixed number of computers, and you have a hash table that contains all the possible configurations and the number of days it would take to update each. Then you problem is a simple lookup. That said, you can solve the problem in a single scan of the list. That is, O(n). What was your solution to the problem?